# How to disable the fatal error (WSOD) protection?

Tags: errors

The fatal error handling was introduced in WordPress 5.1 and 5.2.

It's sometimes referred to as the White Screen Of Death (WSOD) protection.

When working on dev/local installs, we sometimes want to be able to break the sites as needed, and e.g. avoid the email recovery process for the site when working within a *protected endpoint* (see [`is_protected_endpoint()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_protected_endpoint/)):

> The site is experiencing technical difficulties. Please check your
>   site admin email inbox for instructions.

How can we disable the fatal error handling?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

We can modify the *bool* output of the [`wp_is_fatal_error_handler_enabled()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_is_fatal_error_handler_enabled/) function in two ways:

### Constant

Set the `WP_DISABLE_FATAL_ERROR_HANDLER` constant to `true` within the `wp-config.php` file:

```
/**
 * Disable the fatal error handler.
 */
const WP_DISABLE_FATAL_ERROR_HANDLER = true;
```

or

```
define( 'WP_DISABLE_FATAL_ERROR_HANDLER', true );
```

### Filter

Use `wp_fatal_error_handler_enabled` bool filter:

```
/**
 * Disable the fatal error handler.
 */
add_filter( 'wp_fatal_error_handler_enabled', '__return_false' );
```

**Notes**

See ticket [#44458](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/44458)

The `wp_fatal_error_handler_enabled` filter  will override the value of the `WP_DISABLE_FATAL_ERROR_HANDLER` constant.

Also watch out for a possible bool confusion with the constant *disabling* but the filter *enabling*.

In my testing the filter approach, as a *must-use* plugin, is not working as expected, so I'm using the constant instead. Hopefully I can look into this further.

One can also add a custom **drop-in** file `fatal-error-handler.php` into the `wp-content` directory ([src](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/5.2/src/wp-includes/error-protection.php#L88)), to override the [`WP_Fatal_Error_Handler`](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/5.2/src/wp-includes/class-wp-fatal-error-handler.php#L19) class as needed. We must use a different class name and it must define the `handle()` method as the [registered shutdown function](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/5.2/src/wp-includes/error-protection.php#L96).

A simple example to disable it would be to override the default error handler class with a custom one that does nothing:

```
<?php
class WPSE_Fatal_Error_Handler {
    public function handle() {}
}
return new WPSE_Fatal_Error_Handler;
```

Anonymous class in PHP 7+ seems to work as well:

```
<?php
return new Class(){
    public function handle() {}
};
```

It could also extend the default `WP_Fatal_Error_Handler` class if needed.

Then there's the `WP_SANDBOX_SCRAPING` constant. See [#46045](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/46045)

Setting the `WP_DEBUG` as true will **not** disable the WSOD protection. This is by design. See [#46825](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/46825)